# Want to convert PDF form to HTML form ( PDF to HTML) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, pdf

I want to convert PDF which contains form to the HTML form using JavaScript. I am creating a form filling Extension and now i have a task to fill the PDF from that browser extension.So, The way we are find is to convert PDF form and fill it. This is optional, if anybody knows any better way to achieve this(Filling PDF form from Chrome extension) please suggest.